# What artboard sizes are acceptable when using 960 grid system

Tags: adobe-illustrator, mobile, mobile-first

I have trouble understanding this one thing while learning illustrator as a web design tool. Basically, I have to create 3 artboards- for mobile, tablet and monitor, but most teachers use different sizes for the mobile. What sizes are accepted in the business when using 960 grid system?

Answer (score 1):

960 grid system was an interesting option when the 1024x768 px monitors were the standard.

Sayed that it could work for a tablet with that resolution.

But I am afraid that that is an old aproach, so forget about it. Simply define some colums as you want them and let them re-escale.

Use either CSS Flexbox or CSS Grid.